# Pass a variable to the lognam in the hash table in Get-Winevent

Tags: powershell, event-log

I'm trying to change a function using `Get-EventLogs` to use `Get-WinEvent`. Ideally I would like to have one function I can run daily and simply change a few variables to scan different logs.

I have the basic code running, but when I turned it into a function I cannot pass a variable to the LogName in the hash table. I try different combinations of quotes, but no luck.

I get errors that the log doesn't exist with only "-" being in the error.

```
function Check-Eventlogs-v2 {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Type
        #,[string]$Type
        #,[datetime] $date
        ,[int32]$eventtype
        ,[string]$box
    )

    if ($Type -ne '') {
        $servers = Get-Content -LiteralPath "C:\temp\sql_servers3.txt"
        $Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)

        $log = foreach ($box in $servers) {
            Get-WinEvent -Computername $box -LogName = Application -FilterHashTable @{
                Logname   = $Type;
                level     = $eventtype;
                starttime = $Date
            } | Where-Object {
                ($_.Id -ne "2006" -and
                $_.Id -ne "1008" -and
                $_.Id -ne "12289" -and
                $_Logname -eq $Type)
            } | Select-Object @{n='HostName';e={($_.MachineName -split '\.')[0]}}, timecreated, id, message
        }
    } else {
        Write-Warning "'$Type' is not a valid log type."
    }
    return $log
}
```

Comment: Is `[string]$Type` supposed to be commented out?

Comment: Yes, I have it on the top line. Hoard too much code sometimes when I'm trying to get something working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  Got rid of LogName from the filter, and put a ToString match.  You also had a typo in the LogName reference in Where-Object.

```
$log = foreach ($box in $servers) {
            Get-WinEvent -Computername $box -LogName = Application -FilterHashTable @{
                level     = $eventtype;
                starttime = $Date
            } | Where-Object {
                ($_.Id -ne "2006" -and
                $_.Id -ne "1008" -and
                $_.Id -ne "12289" -and
                $_.Logname.ToString() -eq $Type)
            } | Select-Object @{n='HostName';e={($_.MachineName -split '\.')[0]}}, timecreated, id, message
        }
```

Comment: Thx, I'll try it. My script miraculously began to work after I posted this question and it flies compared to using Get-EventLogs. I'm going to write a few more to add to my daily checks and then go back and fix the formatting because the output looks pretty bad in some of them.